# iOS 7: Is it possible to enable voice dictation on fields using the E-mail Address keyboard type?

Tags: ios, ios7

It seems that the voice dictation button doesn't appear on the keyboard if a UITextField is set to use the Email Address keyboard style. I've tried fiddling with the capitalization and autocorrect options. The option does appear if I change the keyboard type on the field.

Is there any way to make dictation work on the Email Address keyboard? It's available in Mail.app, but Apple may well be playing by their own rules there.

Comment: FYI, I think you're right that Apple's playing by their own rules here. A quick survey shows that many (all?) of Apple's other apps suffer the same limitation as our apps. Also, that field is a little special in Mail in that it takes real names and converts them to email addresses based on the address book.